# How to print from struct in C, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and keep getting various errors from all parts of the code?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define SIZE 25
#define NUM_EMP 3


void printEmployees (Employees [NUM_EMP], int c);

typedef struct employee 
{
  char fname[20];
  char lname[20];
  int id;
  char dependents [3][20]; 
                     
} Employees;

void printEmployees(Employees [NUM_EMP], int c) {
  //a function to print what's written in the struct

  printf("%s", Employees[0].fname);
  printf("%s", Employees[0].lname);
  printf("%d", Employees[0].id);
  printf("%s", Employees[0].dependents);

}

int main() {
//populating the struct above

  Employees[NUM_EMP] {
    {"Juan", "Libero", 1, {"son", "daughter", "dog"}},
    {"Stan", "Smith", 2, {"daughter", "daughter", "dog"}},
    {"Russell", "Green", 3, {"son", "son", "cat"}},
  }

  Employees [NUM_EMP];
  printEmployees(Employees,3);

}
```

I'm doing a project right now, my goal is to print what I have under main(), which is information that I tried to put into the struct, which cannot be changed. I just want to print the information I have in main, from the struct, but keep getting errors and I don't know how to fix it. Is there anyone that can help me?

Comment: *keep getting errors*. Show the exact errors. Looks like the code will not compile. But to confirm please show the errors that you are asking about.

Comment: You should at least move the typedef for Employees before the prototype of printEmployees(). In C, typedef names must be declared before being used.

Comment: Seems like you are assuming `Employees` is a variable, although it is a type. You need a variable to that struct.

Comment: @kaylum is right, what are the errors? Compile or runtime errors? AFAIK - the code is not proper syntax - or I do not remember it right since my C times? Or did it change?
AFAIK 
`void printEmployees(Employees [NUM_EMP], int c) {` should be
`void printEmployees(Employees[] employees, int c) {` and using employees instead of Employees inside procedure printEmployees.
And other syntax problems!?

Comment: Suggest you review your text book as it seems you have not understood the basics of declaring and initialising variables. `Employees[NUM_EMP] {` is not valid C syntax. The correct syntax needs to be in the form : `<type> <var_name> = <initializer>`. So something like `Employees employees[NUM_EMP] = { ... };`.

Comment: Form the code posted I can see that you need to learn basics of the C language. Before that it is not possible to write any programs. I advise C book as the best beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is there is no struct variable. `Employees` is just a type, used as an abbreviation for `struct employee`, this will work:

```
void printEmployees(Employees persons[], int c);

void printEmployees(Employees persons[], int c) {
  //a function to print what's written in the struct

  printf("%s ",persons[0].fname);
  printf("%s ", persons[0].lname);
  printf("%d ", persons[0].id);
  printf("%s\n", persons[0].dependents);

}

int main() {
//populating the struct above

  Employees persons[NUM_EMP] =  { 
    {"Jackson", "Leverock", 1, {"son", "daughter", "dog"}},
    {"Stan", "Smith", 2, {"daughter", "daughter", "dog"}},
    {"Russell", "Green", 3, {"son", "son", "cat"}},
  };

  printEmployees(persons,3);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `typedef` implies something's an array but it is not. Make it singular:

```c
typedef struct employee 
{
  char fname[20];
  char lname[20];
  int id;
  char dependents [3][20]; 
                     
} Employee;
```

Then declare an array of them later:

```c
Employee employees[NUM_EMP] = { ... };
```

Note using lower-case for *variable names*.